# pyside, Qt Designer, encapsulated code, and AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'QtGui'

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qt-designer

I used Qt Designer to create a .ui file then pyside-uic to convert to a .py file (ui_mainWindow.py with class `Ui_MainWindow`). I'm heeding the warning not to edit the .ui or .py because any changes there will be overwritten when saving updates in Qt Designer. So I have my own separate code that should be inheriting from it using the python's `super` functionality.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.assignWidgets()
    self.show()
```

I'm able to update labels and respond to buttons and such but I'm not able to use the localization translation stuff. Part of the above class is this function:

```
def connecetSerialPushed(self):
  self.label_connected.setText(self.QtGui.QApplication.translate(self, "Connected: Yes", None, self.QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

If I just do a pure `setText` and the `"Connected: Yes"` string, I get no error. But doing that translation results in an error: AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'QtGui'. I don't get it.. I thought I inherited everything from `Ui_MainWindow` including it's import of `QtGui`. What am I missing?

Comment: `self` is a reference to an object instance of type `MainWindow`, and `QtGui` is the name of a package... not an attribute of a `QMainWindow` from which you're inheriting.

Comment: Hm... that line is almost a straight copy from the Qt Designer / pyside-uic generated code: `self.label_connected.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Connected: No", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))` 
but `"MainWindow"` was also giving me problems so I switched to self. Why does it work there?

Comment: "Almost", but not quite. Note that they're not using `self.QtGui`, they're using `QtGui` to access package contents. I'd recommend a basic Python tutorial b/c the problem you're having here is not really Qt-based; it's a lack of Python-specific understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside my separate code, I did

```
from PySide import QtGui
```

and then changed the translation line to

```
self.label_connected.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Connected: Yes", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Thanks [ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4594973/ray) for clearing up my confusion.